# Get font name from FontFamily in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, fonts, font-family

I'm currently working on a little font organization/preview application for myself, however, I'm having a hard time getting the exact information I need.

I've found that I can load an external font by just creating a new FontFamily object with the font's file location as its source. However, I can't find a way to get a font's specific font name back. I know I can use FontFamily.FamilyNames to get the font's *family* name back, but that's useless to me when I have multiple fonts with the same family being displayed. I'd like to actually display the specific name for the specific font.

Is there any way to do this? I currently display the file name instead, but it's incredibly sloppy because I have to iterate through every file in a directory and call Fonts.GetFontFamilies() on each just so I can get the actual file name(FontFamily's Source property only gives WPF's makeshift family-name source instead of something useful).

Comment: [FontFamily::GetTypefaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.fontfamily.gettypefaces.aspx) and then [Typeface::FaceNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.typeface.facenames.aspx) doesn't get you what you want?

Answer (score 2):

This is what I am doing:

```
        ListBoxItem listBoxItem = null;
        foreach (FontFamily fontFamily in Fonts.SystemFontFamilies)
        {
            listBoxItem = new ListBoxItem();
            listBoxItem.Content = fontFamily;
            listBoxItem.FontFamily=fontFamily; // Shows Font Text in the Font
            FontFamilyListBox.Items.Add(listBoxItem);
        }
```

Comment: So a simple `ToString()` on font family seems to work.